# Typescript implementing interface property

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have declared interface as below

```
interface Base {
    required: string;
}
```

I have implemented interface in class like

```
class MyClass implements Base{
    method(): void {
        console.log(this.required);
    }
}
```

But I am getting following error

> severity: 'Error' message: 'Class 'MyClass' incorrectly implements
>   interface 'Base'.   Property 'required' is missing in type 'MyClass'.'
>   at: '5,7' source: 'ts'
>
> severity: 'Error' message: 'Property 'required' does not exist on type
>   'MyClass'.' at: '7,26' source: 'ts'

if I declare    `required: string;` once again in class then no error

```
interface Base {
    required: string;
}

class MyClass implements Base{
 required: string;

    method(): void {
      this.required="ddd";
        console.log(this.required);
        // you can access HTMLElement
    }
}

var ss=new MyClass();
ss.method();
```

Comment: interface are nothing in javascript, if you implement a class from an interface, you need provide all required fields.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to delcare `requried: string` twice use `class` instate `interface` for `Base` and extends instate implements.

```
class Base {
    required: string;
}

class MyClass extends Base{
    method(): void {
      this.required="ddd";
        console.log(this.required);
        // you can access HTMLElement
    }
}
```

Check it out in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20required%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20extends%20Base%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20method()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.required%3D%22ddd%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.required)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20you%20can%20access%20HTMLElement%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20ss%3Dnew%20MyClass()%3B%0D%0Ass.method()%3B).

Comment: Thanks @Magu.but it looks like no use to declare property in interface

Answer (score 1):

That's how interfaces work. If you define a property in the interface then you need to define the same property in the class where you are implementing the interface. If you would like to use required property without re define the property, you should create a class an extend it.

Comment: Thanks@Andrés Andrade.but it looks like no use to declare property in interface

Answer (score 1):

Your error is correct. If your `class` implements an `interface`, it must also implement all the **required properties and methods**. If you want not to implement some properties or methods, you can declare them as `optional` with `?` symbol.

```
interface Base {
    required: string;
    someProperty?: string; // << look at the symbol `?` in the end of the property
}
```

Here you can implement the interface and left the `someProperty`

```
class MyClass implements Base{
    required: string;
    // someProperty is missing here, because it is optional     

    method(): void {
      this.required="ddd";
        console.log(this.required);
        // you can access HTMLElement
    }
}
```

And not only you can implement interfaces. Also you can use them as a type. If you have an interface

```
interface Base {
   required: string;
}
```

you can create an object which is the type of that interface

```
const obj: Base = { };
```

But here you will get an error because if your object is of type `Base`, you need to provide all required properties. So you need to write

```
const obj: Base = { required: 'Yes' };
```

This will protect your code from logical errors and your code will be strong typed also for object, for which you don't want to create a class, but you want to said what `shape` it must be.

**Example**

You have an interface

```
interface Name {
   name: string
}
```

and have classes

```
class Car implements Name {
    name: string;
    engine: string
    constructor(name: string, engine: string){
       this.name = name;
       this.engine = engine;
    }
}

class Person implements Name {
    name: string;
    surname: string;

    constructor(name: string, surname: string){
       this.name = name;
       this.surname = surname;
    }
}

var arr: Name = [new Car('Car', 'JZ'), new Person('Name', 'Surname')];
```

here `arr` is an array of type `Name`. So if you get `arr[0]`, and call on it `.engine`, intelisense will throw an error that there is no `engine` property in type `Name`. But you can be sure, that every object in that array has `name` property, because the type of that array is `Name` and it has an required property `name`.

Comment: thanks@Suren Srapyan.but it looks like no use to declare property in interface

Comment: Why there is no use? You can use type detection in your code. Consider you have many classes that implements an interface, so you can assign you values the `interface` type, to make sure that object at least has the properties which are in the interface

Comment: @Suren.If you dont mind can you give me better example to prove this.Thanks